# Uncheck "Use this field’s values as search keywords?" by default?

Tags: craft3

Is there a way to have the "Use this field’s values as search keywords?" option unchecked by default when creating a new field? Our searchindex table is getting bloated by data that doesn't need to be in there. I'm clearing it out now, but it would be really cool to have that checkbox be unchecked unless someone specifically wants it to be a keyword for search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Craft 3.5, that setting will be disabled by default when creating new fields (see [craftcms/cms#6390](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6390)).

Comment: Thanks BK! Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but you couple probably hack something together using some JS and the [CPJS](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-cpjs) plugin.